# 'Realm/Realm.h' file not found in iOS when Archiving

Tags: ios, app-store, realm

When Archiving the project for Enterprise Distribution I'm getting an error "'Realm/Realm.h' file not found" .

Screenshot:

[image: Actual Error Text]

Realm works fine both on simulator and devices when I run it. But the problem is when Archive the project.

Comment: Try clean and clean build folder (option key + clean), if it doesnt work, delete derived folder and try archive again

Comment: @RezonanulAlamRiad  your problem is solved or not after clean the folder and deleting the derived file...

Comment: Tried many times, didn't work :(

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer: Got you and Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your answers. my problem is solved. But I'm very sorry that, I can't remember now how I was able to fix it. Most probably I had to do a "pod update" and i didn't override any settings from pods.xcodeproj to my main app .xcodeproj, I used "$(inherited)" as cocoapods suggested in command line. Cheers.

Comment: After learn for some hours of the same matter, I think maybe I find the reason. Commonly after pod install, the Pods-{project}.Debug.xcconfig file while add ""${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Realm/Realm.framework/Headers"" to HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS. But when you try to use Realm when project not build again,  no Realm file in PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR. Only when rebuild the project , you will find Realm files in PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR, and then you can Realm files now.

Answer (score 0):

See if framework search path is set correctly for release build.

Comment: I've put the framework search path for Release as well. Even though Debug and Release both works fine. The problem is only on Archive.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the same issue with these steps:

1. Clean project
2. Delete 'Derived Data'
3. Set a correct provisioning profile for Realm subproject (I'm not a fan of Cocoa pods)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe will be halpful for someone
I also had realm-js-ios not found error in xcode

```
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '17.2'

          # Ensure GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS is initialized with an array including $(inherited), and add a custom definition.
          # This line ensures that the existing definitions are preserved and new ones are added.
          config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
          config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] << '_LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_UNARY_BINARY_FUNCTION'
        end
      end
```